# Autofac interceptor not working for some classes

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, autofac

I have to do some extra logic layer on existing classes. I'm using `autofac`.

The project is `Windows service` having also `Kestrel` server. `Program.cs` e.g.

```
void Main(string[] args) {
   var customQueue = new CustomQueue();
   var someClass = new SomeClass(customQueue);
   var randomClass = new RandomClass();

   // do some logic here with using declared instances

   var server = new Server(someClass, randomClass);
   server.Start();
}
```

And here is the `Server.cs`

```
class Server {
   private IWebHost _host;

   public Server(SomeClass cls, RandomClass cls1) { 
         // set to fields
   }

   void Start() {
      _host = new WebHostBuilder()
                  .UseKestrel() 
                  .ConfigureServices(services => 
                  {
                      services.AddAutoFac(); // first as per doc in order to scaffold 'ConfigureContainer'?
                      services.AddSingleton(someClass); // fields
                      services.AddSingleton(randomClass); // fields
                  })
                  .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                  .ConfigureAppConfiguration(...)
                  .ConfigureLogging(...);
                  .UseStartup<Startuo>()
                  .Build();
      _host.StartAsync(); 
   }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public ILifetimeScope AutofacContainer { get; private set; }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // create a container-builder and register dependencies
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // populate the service-descriptors added to `IServiceCollection`
        // BEFORE you add things to Autofac so that the Autofac
        // registrations can override stuff in the `IServiceCollection`
        // as needed
        builder.Populate(services);
        builder.RegisterType<SomeClass>()
            .As<ISomeClass>()
            .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
            .InterceptedBy(typeof(SomeClassInterceptor));
        builder.Register(_ => new SomeClassInterceptor());

        AutofacContainer = builder.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(AutofacContainer);
    }
}
```

And last **SomeClassInterceptor.cs**

```
public class SomeClassInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {

        try
        {

            invocation.Proceed();

            if (invocation.ReturnValue is Task taskResult)
            {
                taskResult.ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OOHH YEAHH");
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WOW");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTIOOOOOOOOOOOOONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried with `Named` and `Typed` registration with having `Intercept(...)` attribute but still no success. Nothing gets triggered. 
Also `ISomeClass` is inheriting other interfaces, I've tried setting `.As<>()` also with those but no.

What am I missing?

Comment: I try to reproduce but "it works on my machine"

Answer (score 0):

In order to let the interceptor works. The class should be build by *Autofac*.

```
services.AddAutofac();
services.AddSingleton(someClass);
services.AddSingleton(randomClass);
```

In your case you configure *Autofac* using the `AddAutofac` method then add `SomeClass` as a singleton using the `AddSingleton` which will override the *Autofac* configuration. There is no way that *Autofac* can inject the interceptor in it.

If you want to register `SomeClass` as singleton you should register it using the `SingleInstance()` method

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeClass>()
       .As<ISomeClass>()
       .SingleInstance()
       .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
       .InterceptedBy(typeof(SomeClassInterceptor));
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no success.

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint on the constructor of `SomeClass` and check on the stack trace that it is created by Autofac ?

Comment: Its not called from autofac at all. `someClass` is already an instance of the class (you can see in `Program.cs`). I've also tried to remove `services.AddSingleton(someClass)` and directly register this instance with `builder.RegisterInstance(someClass)` but still not triggered.

Comment: by using `RegisterInstance` you are not letting *Autofac* create the instance. You specify an instance that you create yourself. Autofac can't inject the interceptor behavior in a already created instance.